# removing NaN values in python pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Data is of income of adults from census data, rows look like:

```
31, Private, 84154, Some-college, 10, Married-civ-spouse, Sales, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 38, NaN, >50K
48, Self-emp-not-inc, 265477, Assoc-acdm, 12, Married-civ-spouse, Prof-specialty, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
```

I'm trying to remove all rows with NaNs from a DataFrame loaded from a CSV file in pandas.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> income = pd.read_csv('income.data')
>>> income['type'].unique()
array([ State-gov,  Self-emp-not-inc,  Private,  Federal-gov,  Local-gov,
    NaN,  Self-emp-inc,  Without-pay,  Never-worked], dtype=object)
>>> income.dropna(how='any') # should drop all rows with NaNs
>>> income['type'].unique()
array([ State-gov,  Self-emp-not-inc,  Private,  Federal-gov,  Local-gov,
    NaN,  Self-emp-inc,  Without-pay,  Never-worked], dtype=object)
    Self-emp-inc, nan], dtype=object) # what??
>>> income = income.dropna(how='any') # ok, maybe reassignment will work?
>>> income['type'].unique()
array([ State-gov,  Self-emp-not-inc,  Private,  Federal-gov,  Local-gov,
    NaN,  Self-emp-inc,  Without-pay,  Never-worked], dtype=object) # what??
```

I tried with a smaller `example.csv`:

```
label,age,sex
1,43,M
-1,NaN,F
1,65,NaN
```

And `dropna()` worked just fine here for both categorical and numerical NaNs. What is going on? I'm new to Pandas, just learning the ropes.

Comment: Try assigning the line `income.dropna(how='any')` to a variable and check the values on that. `dropna()` is not inplace by default (I think the inplace option may have been added after .12).

Comment: @TomAugspurger: No also doesn't work.

Comment: Tried ```df.dropna(thresh = 1)``` ? More info about your data would be good..

Comment: didn't work either. both with and without reassignment

Comment: Again, how does your dataframe and input data from the csv look like? Are there only strings in the "income.data" (is NaN -> "NaN"). Maybe you need to set the ```na_values``` paramter in the read_csv, but we need a more detailed info about the raw data and your dataframe after the import (try income.head())

Comment: I just copy-pasted your data from above into a blank csv, imported it to pandas. It looks like the "NaN" is recognized as a string with a leading whitespace " NaN". Use ```na_values=" NaN"``` int hthe csv-import, then the ```dropna``` works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment: The "NaN" has a leading whitespace (at least in the data you provided). Therefore, you need to specifiy the `na_values` paramter in the `read_csv` function.

Try this one:

```
df = pd.read_csv("income.csv",header=None,na_values=" NaN")
```

This is why your second example works, because there is no leading whitespace here.

Comment: ah yep...that does it. is there a way to make pandas strip elements in CSVs? that would seem like a fairly common task (one I just expected to be built in).

Comment: No, not by default i guess (in some cases, whitespace may be usefull). But you could use ```pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), skipinitialspace=True)``` (i.e. the skipinitalspace-option, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html), or you could try using " ," or a regular expression as a custom seperator.

Answer (score 1):

#### Drop all rows with NaN values

```
df2=df.dropna()
df2=df.dropna(axis=0)
```

#### Reset index after drop

```
df2=df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Drop row that has all NaN values

```
df2=df.dropna(how='all')
```

#### Drop rows that has NaN values on selected columns

```
df2=df.dropna(subset=['length','Height'])
```

Comment: Try your code before posting your answer. Your code will not remove NaN values.